# Plot line graphs with with a factor variable on x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I failed to plot a line graph on x axis using initials of months with this code:

```
yrange<-range(c(Estimate, lcl,ucl))
plot(nmonth, Estimate, type = "b", pch = 20, ylim = yrange, 
xlab = "Months",  ylab = expression(hat(beta) * " estimates" * " & " * "   confidence "  * " levels "))
lines(nmonth, ucl, lty = 2)
lines(nmonth, lcl, lty = 2)
abline(h = 0, lty = 3)
```

and with this as well.

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=nmonth, y=Estimate)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_line(size=0.1) + geom_line(aes(y = ucl)) + geom_line(aes(y = lcl))
```

Using numeric month(nmonth) I can produce a plot, but labels are not what I wished to have.
How can I plot with all initials of the months on x axis?

The data is this one:

```
structure(list(Estimate = c(0.00571942142644563, 0.0111649330056159, 
0.0143761435860972, 0.00739757934210567, 0.00110764672100624, 
0.00168566337236168, 0.00392476757483504, 0.00234423892025447, 
0.000166724737089459, -0.0014580012873366, -0.00197786373686253, 
-0.00216289530501664), se = c(0.004018593736177, 0.0040534199847734, 
0.0041113846550833, 0.00402501059422328, 0.00393358629717884, 
0.00370406599461686, 0.003796651550619, 0.00392460643968604, 
0.00376380927915926, 0.00391408378704714, 0.00388845564349082, 
0.00394365265230613), nmonth = 1:12, month = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("J", 
"F", "M", "A", "S", "O", "N", "D"), class = "factor"), lcl = c(-0.00215702229646129, 
0.00322022983546004, 0.00631782966213393, -0.000491441422571959, 
-0.00660218242146429, -0.00557430597708737, -0.0035166694643782, 
-0.00534798970153017, -0.00721034145006269, -0.00912960550994899, 
-0.00959923679810454, -0.00989245450353666), ucl = c(0.0135958651493525, 
0.0191096361757718, 0.0224344575100605, 0.0152866001067833, 0.00881747586347677, 
0.00894563272181073, 0.0113662046140483, 0.0100364675420391, 
0.00754379092424161, 0.00621360293527579, 0.00564350932437948, 
0.00556666389350337)), .Names = c("Estimate", "se", "nmonth", 
"month", "lcl", "ucl"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: There's a problem with your data, because if you only take the first letter of the month, you cannot distinguish January, June and July for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ggplot2, it is easier if you first melt your data this way :

```
df <- melt(df, id.vars=c("month","nmonth"))
```

Then you can directly do :

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=month, y=value, group=variable)) + geom_line(aes(color=variable))
```

[image]

Note that the graph is not correct because you are using only the first letter of your months names.

Comment: Thanks Juba. I have changed the month names to abbreviated month and it worked fine.